# Inaccessible host: `dynamodb-local' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the `localhost

Tags: javascript, docker, aws, lambda, dynamodb

Hola como puedo conectar mi app de `SAM` a `dynamoDB` que tengo corriendo y funcionando dentro de `docker`, puedo conectarme con cualquier cliente incluido `serverless` pero `SAM` la `M****a` esta no puede

he intentado de estas 2 formas

```
sam local invoke getAllItemsFunction
```

y

```
sam local start-api
```

el resultado es el mismo, o que mas me falta?, esa cosa me tiene loco ya una semana, solo encuentro guias con `dynamodb` ya desde `AWS` o no hay forma de trabajarlo solo localmente?

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"UnknownEndpoint","errorMessage":"Inaccessible host: `dynamodb-local' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the `localhost' region.","code":"UnknownEndpoint","message":"Inaccessible host: `dynamodb-local' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the `localhost' region.","region":"localhost","hostname":"dynamodb-local","retryable":true,"originalError":{"errorType":"NetworkingError","errorMessage":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dynamodb-local","code":"NetworkingError","message":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dynamodb-local","errno":-3008,"syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"dynamodb-local","region":"localhost","retryable":true,"time":"2022-07-04T22:48:27.668Z","stack":["Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dynamodb-local","
```

**lambda**

```
const tableName = process.env.SAMPLE_TABLE;

const { DynamoDB } = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new DynamoDB({
  endpoint: "http://dynamodb-local:8000",
  //endpoint: "http://dynamodb:8000",
  //endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
  //endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  region: "localhost",
});

exports.getAllItemsHandler = async (event) => {
  var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
  };
  const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
  const items = data.Items;

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(items),
  };
  return response;
};
```

**template.yml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  demoapp

Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Tracing: Active

Resources:
  getAllItemsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/get-all-items.getAllItemsHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: A simple example includes a HTTP get method to get all items from a DynamoDB table.
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref SampleTable
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SAMPLE_TABLE: !Ref SampleTable
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET

  SampleTable:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable
    Properties:
      PrimaryKey:
        Name: id
        Type: String
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 2
        WriteCapacityUnits: 2

Outputs:
  WebEndpoint:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

**dynamo-docker**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dynamodb-local:
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "./docker/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
```

Answer (score 0):

En endpoint: tienes que poner la ip de la LAN local de la tarjeta de red de tu máquina donde también levantas el Docker de Dynamo y no la de localhost (ej: 192.168.1.20, según tu configuración LAN). También asegúrate que puedas ver el Dynamo desde esa ip y puerto (por defecto deberías poder, sino revisa tu configuración del Docker cuando levantas los contenedores de Dynamo). No funciona con la de localhost porque SAM también levanta contenedores y desde dentro del contenedor el locahost es el propio contenedor (el de Lambda o API, según lo que hayan levantado en local).